# Xamarin.iOS Error logging suggestion

Tags: xamarin.ios, error-logging

What approach should I use while logging errors in a Xamarin.iOS mobile application ? 


1.Database
2.File
3.Or Any other better approach or third-party tool


Thanks in Advance !

Comment: which error do you want to log, exception ? build error? crash info?

Comment: Exceptions and Crash info ?